# BST conversion to the tree of symmetric structure

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

(I've seen some very similiar excercises, but all of them for a regular binary trees). As in the title I have to propose an algorithm to convert BST to another BST with symmetric structure, which includes the same values as the previous one. For example

[image]

My idea was to build a new tree from the beggining. I would start with a new root that would be in a symmetric position of the original one in a sorted array of values from the original tree. In the example above: 3 5 6 7 12  number 7 will be the new root, because it has reversed number of nodes at its left/right side in comparison to the previous root 5. But it doesn't solve the problem completely, because the new tree depends on the order of insertion. I wanted to end it with performing rotations depending on the balance. My question is: does this tree have to be AVL tree so i can perform rotations (this would mean there's an error in the excercise). Or is there and easier way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem in two steps:

1. Swap the left and right child pointers in every node.  This will mirror the tree left-to right, reversing the order of all the values.
2. Do a forward in-order traversal from the start and a backward in-order traversal from the end. Proceed in lock step, swapping values between the forward and backward positions until they meet.  This will reverse the order of values back to their original order, while preserving the new tree structure.